# Edit user profile with delegated permission in native app. Which fields are editable?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

**Scenario**: Native app with user (user role) present including a user profile page allowing the user to update his profile.

**Azure AD v2.0 endpoint** used & **app registration done** accordingly. App is used by many tenants, therefore we have **admin consent flow included in the apps sign-up flow**.

**Account Types:** Work & School Account

**Admin consented scopes (delegated permission per tenant on registered app):**

- User.ReadWrite
- Directory.AccessAsUser.All (Admin Only)
- Directory.ReadWrite.All (Admin Only)
- User.ReadWrite.All (Admin Only)

**From the documentation:**

[User permission](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions)

*User.ReadWrite and User.Readwrite.All delegated permissions allow the app to update the following profile properties for work or school accounts:*

- aboutMe
- birthday
- hireDate
- interests
- mobilePhone
- mySite
- pastProjects
- photo
- preferredName
- responsibilities
- schools
- skills

**Question 1:** Did we understood the terms and documentation correctly?

**Question 2:** What about other user fields not in this list? Is there no Graph Scenario at all to change them? The documentation is a bit unclear in terms of if possible with user delegated rights or just application delegated right or not possible at all.

**Concrete:**

- Job Title? Can a user with delegated permission ever updated this field or do we need application permission to do so?
- User Profile Photo? Can a user with delegated permission update his/her own profile picture or do we need application permission to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next sentence after that list you referenced from the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#remarks-17) explains this:

> With the `User.ReadWrite.All` **application permission**, the app can update all of the declared properties of work or school accounts except for password.

So yes, you can only update the full set of `user` properties using Application permissions (aka the `Client_Credentials` flow).

Comment: Thanks. What about the profile photo? Can this be set without application permission? On the update photo doc it says no, but its in the list above. Any advise here?

Comment: The docs state "To update the photo of **any user** in the organization, your app must have the `User.ReadWrite.All` application permission". So if you're only updating the current user (i.e. `/me`) then you can use delegated. If you want to update all users in your tenant then you would need to use client_credentials.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying. Now I struggle with the microsoft.graph .net library and raised an issue here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/237

Comment: One more question. Where in the documentation can I see which user fields are editable at all with delegated permission? E.g. the aboutMe field? This seems to be limited to app permission but I don't find a nice overview.

Comment: Anything not specifically called out in that list you referenced requires Application scopes. Also keep in mind that AD Connect can affect this as well since it will lock any attributes it is syncing from a local AD instance.